# C# mail is not displaying link in my email

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I am trying to send email with unsubsrible link in my aspx page. But when I check my email id It display only text. There was no link. Here is my code generate a email

```
                string bodyContent = CKEditor1.Text;
                string userLink = "http://www.abc.in/Message.aspx?action=rmsb&oldsubuser=";
                string footerLink = "</br></br></br>You are receiving this mail because you have subscribed to our newsletter. If you do not wish to receive the mail, Click <a href='" + userLink + "" + ids[i].ToString() + "'>Here</a>";                    
                bodyContent = bodyContent + footerLink;
                EmailSend newsletter = new EmailSend();
                newsletter.NewsLetterSend(ids[i].ToString(), bodyContent.Replace("'", "''"), txtSubject.Text.Replace("'", "''"));
                //EmailSend.SendMailMessage("faredpt@gmail.com", ids[i].ToString(), "", "", txtSubject.Text, bodyContent);
                bodyContent = bodyContent.Replace(footerLink, " ");
```

Here is the code for NewsLetterSend function

```
 public void NewsLetterSend(string getemailAdd, string msgBody, string subject)
        {
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

            //set the addresses
            mail.From = new MailAddress("admin@abc.in", "admin@abc.in");
            mail.To.Add(getemailAdd.Trim());

            //set the content
            mail.Subject = subject;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mail.Body = msgBody;
            mail.Priority = MailPriority.High;


            //set the smtp settings
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("abc.in");
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;

            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin@abc.in", "i@abc!23#");
            //smtp.Port = 3535;
            smtp.Port = 25;
            //send email
            smtp.Send(mail);
            return;
        }
```

Now this code is sending email successfully but unable to add link in my email. It show me simple text 
Please tell me why this happening

Comment: `bodyContent.Replace("'", "''")` why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are replacing the quotation mark in `href` with two quotation marks!

Invalid statement: `bodyContent.Replace("'", "''")`

This will render your HTML invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to replace `</br></br></br>` with `<br/><br/><br/>`? Probably because of invalid `br` tags your email is considered as not valid HTML and links become broken.